# The height of the combobox changes when I select an item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox that binds to a collection in which I want to collapse some of them according to a condtion.

The problem is that if in my view model I select an item that it is collapsed in my view, still is displayed the text of the DisplayMemeberPath, so I am trying to set the text of the texblock to an empty string.

I think that I get it, the problem with my solution it is that the hight of the combobx changes when I select and item, so the height it is very few and I can't see the combobox completely.

The code that I am using is this:

```
<ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{x:Static vg:MyCOllection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
    
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding MyPropertyInItem}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value=""/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Perhaps there are better ways to achieve, so I could accept another solutions, how to set the text of the text block in the case the selected item is one of the items collapsed in the combobox.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you collapse the container instead of filtering the source collection? Or simply set the `Text` property of the item to be hidden to an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DisplayMemberPath` in your scenario. This will create a `TextBlock` as string value presenter for the selection box to replace the `ComboBoxItem`.

Instead of `DisplayMemberPath` create a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
  <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyDataType}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyPropertyInItem}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```